# How to bring singular and plural conditions under a single sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number

I am doing a sentence like this:

> He may undergo a scan,(or scans). The resulting image/images will be examined by the doctor.

I am thinking of this one:

> He may undergo a group of scans. The resulting group of images will be examined by the doctor.

Comment: @minus voter, What is the reason to downvote this?

Comment: Not my downvote, but it may be that your question is a little confusing or your solutions are perfectly fine, and the downvoter doesn't understand where the problem lies. To me, both sentences sound fine, especially after WS2's spelling edit. Ahh, could be the downvote was for this spelling error—who will ever know! EDIT: upvoted

Comment: So is what you're asking whether *"a scan"* could be a special case of *"a group of scans"*? Why don't you ask the question explicitly instead of making people have to guess?

Comment: You **can** use the plural with a singular-plural combination: "He may undergo a scan or two. The resulting **images** ..."

Comment: Please visit [ell.se]

Answer (score 2):

Yes. 'He may undergo one or more scans. The resulting image(s) will be examined by the doctor'. That makes perfect grammatical sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just make everything plural. The use of *may* already states that maybe nothing will happen. So, *may undergo scans* means "zero or more". The result would naturally be zero or more images.  Since the meaning can be inferred, you don't need to clutter your sentences.